# Polygon shape based on attributes (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I'm using the "Select by Location" to select features from one layer, based on a polygon in another layer. It' working just fine.

Is it possible to create polygons (cones / point of view) based one these attributes:

- Length (meters),
- Direction (degress 0-360),
- Angle (degrees 0-180) - normal range will be 10-60

Comment: Have you tried the [Create Wedge Buffers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=create%20wedge%20buffer#create-wedge-buffers) processing tool?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.